# ¿Como subir información a Cloud Firestore de Firebase desde Android Studio con Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy tratando de subir información en forma de HashMap desde un proyecto en Android Studio a Cloud Firestore.

Me gustaria que la información del HashMap se almacene como un objetoGasto más, en la ruta: count > APRIL > gastos.
Y quedase añadido junto a los que ya hay.

[image: Ubicación de Cloud Firestore]

El problema es a la hora de definir la ruta de referencia a donde debe almacenarse el HashMap.

Este es el metodo de debe almacenar el HashMap

```
Map<String, Object> objetoGasto = new HashMap<>();
                    objetoGasto.put("nombre", "Juan");
                    objetoGasto.put("categoria", "Comida");
                    objetoGasto.put("cantidad", 1.34);


                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uid = user.getUid();
                
                db.collection("users").document(uid+"/count/APRIL/gastos/objetoGasto")
                        .set(objetoGasto)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                tostada("Gasto añadido");
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                tostada("Error al crear el gasto");
                            }
                        });
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:
[image]
Se crea una colección a parte.

Toda infomación ayuda. Gracias!

**ACTUALIZACION**:
Con FieldPath.of() he llegado hasta el valor, el problema es que no se añade el registro, se actualizan los valores que hay:

```
                Map<String, Object> objetoGasto = new HashMap<>();
                    objetoGasto.put("nombre", "Juan");
                    objetoGasto.put("categoria", "Comida");
                    objetoGasto.put("cantidad", 1.34);


                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uid = user.getUid();

                db.collection("users").document(uid)
                .update(FieldPath.of("count","APRIL","gastos"), objetoGasto)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                //tostada("Btcs actualizado");
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Yo lo que haría sería descargar el objeto añadir lo que quieres y volverlo a subir o actualizarlo. Se que es poco eficiente pero es lo que hago yo con firebase.

Comment: No queda claro en qué ruta debe quedar el objeto ¿? Tampoco queda claro si en dicha ruta puede darse el caso de que haya más de un objeto, si es así quizá debas replantear la estructura. Pulsa en [edit] para aclarar tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias @SpartanVII . Estoy intentando ahora hacer eso, ¿sabes como indicar la ruta para acceder al valor? Estoy porbando a editar los objetos "gastos" añadir el nuevo y ahora quiero subirlos todos. Dejo aquí lo que tengo:        ` HashMap<String, Object> usuarioFinal = (HashMap<String, Object>) document.getData();
                            usuarioFinal.put("count + JANUARY + gastos", gastos); `

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano . Ya lo he editado. En "count > APRIL > gastos"

Comment: @AdriánBenitez No entiendo lo que preguntas. ¿Tu problema ahora es que no sabes como descargar los gastos?

Comment: @SpartanVII Descargarlos sí se, el problema es para subrilos todos a "count > APRIL > gastos" y que se sustituyan. Gracias.